# how to show checked div on a div that has an image

Tags: jquery

I am currently working for a survey project. I have seen image questions in some surveys.
i want to implement it in my project. so i have thought like this.

here is my code.

```
<div  id="image1"    onclick="Imagecheckbox(this);">
    <img src="https://www.google.co.in/images/srpr/logo3w.png" alt="Image not found" />
</div>
<div  id="image2"    onclick="Imagecheckbox(this);">
   <img src="https://www.google.co.in/images/srpr/logo3w.png" alt="Image not found" />
</div>
 <div  id="image3"    onclick="Imagecheckbox(this);">
    <img src="https://www.google.co.in/images/srpr/logo3w.png" alt="Image not found" />
</div>
```

so when i click on any image i want to show some thing like this.
[image]

so i am creating a div dynamically and appending to this. but its not working.
here is my code.

```
   function Imagecheckbox(div) {
        var clickeddiv = $('#' + div.id);
        $("<div id='mydiv' style='background:yellow;z-index:1;height:100;width:100;align:right;vertical-align:bottom;etc...'></div>").appendTo($(clickeddiv)); 
    }
```

How can i do this ?
thanks.

Comment: You need to make it `position: absolute`, and be contained within the same container as the image you want the checkbox to be displayed over, and that container must be made `position: relative`.

Comment: Alternative: Show bigger image in background and when it is clicked show marked image as img tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, avoid the use of `onclick` attributes. If you already have included jQuery on your page, you may as well make best use of it.

To achieve this you need to add `position: relative;` to your `div` elements which contain the images, and `position: absolute` to the `div` which contains the ticks.

HTML

```
<div id="images">
    <div>
        <img src="https://www.google.co.in/images/srpr/logo3w.png" alt="Image not found" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <img src="https://www.google.co.in/images/srpr/logo3w.png" alt="Image not found" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <img src="https://www.google.co.in/images/srpr/logo3w.png" alt="Image not found" />
    </div>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
var $tick = $("<div />").addClass("tick");
$("#images div").click(function() {
    if ($(this).find(".tick").length) {
        $(this).find(".tick").remove();
    }
    else {
        $(this).append($tick);
    }
});
```

CSS

```
#images div {
    position: relative;
}
#images div .tick {
    background-image: url('tick.gif');
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 25px; /* amend as needed */
    height: 25px; /* amend as needed */
    position: absolute;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function Imagecheckbox(div) {
    var clickeddiv = $('#' + $(div).attr('id'));
    $("<div id='mydiv' style='background:yellow;z-index:1;height:100;width:100;align:right;vertical-align:bottom;etc...'></div>").appendTo($(clickeddiv)); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to create and remove an element with jQuery at every click: you could obtain the same effect styling a pseudoelement, e.g.

**HTML**

```
<div id="images">
    <div id="image1">
        <img src="https://www.google.co.in/images/srpr/logo3w.png">
    </div>
    <div id="image2">
        <img src="https://www.google.co.in/images/srpr/logo3w.png">
    </div>
    ...
</div>
```

**jQuery**
(just a `toggleClass()` along with event delegation on a parent element, so you will avoid to attach an handler for every `div`)

```
$('#images').on('click', 'div', function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('selected');
});
```

**CSS**

```
#images > div.selected {
   position  : relative;
   z-index   : 1;
}

#images > div.selected:after {
   content   : "";
   position  : absolute;
   right     : 0;
   bottom    : 0;
   width     : ...;
   height    : ...;
   background : url(selected-tick.gif) center center no-repeat;   
}
```

pseudoelements work on all modern browser and even on `IE8+`